# YARN parameter to take heap dump before killing container

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, heap-dump

I have a long-running yarn application (not m/r) with containers that occasionally exceed the yarn memory limit, at which point yarn kills the offending containers. I am finding it difficult to determine what is causing the heap growth. Is there a yarn parameter I can set that would tell yarn to take a heap dump before killing the container?